# jQuery Toggle Text With Single Button

Tags: jquery, html

**How do I toggle text size with a single button?**
Toggling between 14pt and 16pt would be cool.
*Thanks*

Example 'two buttons no toggle'

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
$('input').click(function(){
var ourText = $('p');
var currFontSize = ourText.css('fontSize');
var finalNum = parseFloat(currFontSize, 10);
var stringEnding = currFontSize.slice(-2);
if(this.id == 'large') {
finalNum *= 1.2;
}
else if (this.id == 'small'){
finalNum /=1.2;
}
ourText.css('fontSize', finalNum + stringEnding);
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Toggle Text jQuery Single Button? </h2>

<!--NEED A SINGLE BUTTON TOGGLE-->
<input type='button' value='< text small' id='small' />
<input type='button' value='text large>' id='large' />

<p>My Text!!!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  var fontSizes = [14, 16];
  $('input').click(function() {
    $('p').css('font-size', fontSizes[0] + 'pt');
    fontSizes.reverse();
  })
```

Or, using CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  p {
    font-size: 14pt;
  }    
  p.larger {
    font-size: 16pt;
  }
</style>

<script>    
  $('input').click(function() {
    $('p').toggleClass('larger');
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

## CSS

```
.small-text { font-size: 14pt; }
.large-text { font-size: 16pt; }
```

## Javascript

```
$(function(){
    var textSizeButton = $("#text-size-toggle");
    textSizeButton.click(function(){
        var body = $('body'); // or any selector you want
        if (body.hasClass('small-text')) {
            body
                .removeClass('small-text')
                .addClass('large-text');
            textSizeButton.setAttr('value', 'Go smaller');
        }
        else {
            body
                .removeClass('large-text')
                .addClass('small-text');
            textSizeButton.setAttr('value', 'Go larger');
        }
    });
});
```

## HTML

```
<input type="button" id="text-size-toggle" value="Go larger" />
```

Answer (score 1):

use jquery ui, than you can make a button from a checkbox. you can download here : http://jqueryui.com/download

```
 $("#check").button();
    $("#check").click(function () {
        var ourText = $('p');
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            ourText.css('fontSize', 'large')
        }
        else {
            ourText.css('fontSize', 'small')
        } 
    });
```